# certificate status issued

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Hye,

I'm not sure what is the problem is, but whenever I want to submit my app, this will occur,
afterthat i've tried to revoke my certificate and quest it back, the status were "issued" . How can i solve this problem ? tq.

Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the distribution profile to sign your app for submission, and not the developer profile?

It's a common cause of this failure.

It could also be that you are using Xcode 4.5 or iOS6 (which are pre-release) and that is preventing submission.

In general - I find the Apple [Technical Note on Code Signing Issues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html) to be a great reference for solving such problems.